# 3D surface plot with section plane

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, matplotlib-3d

Basically I have a surface plot consisting of a set of time series, and I would like to add a section plan at a specific height, to better understand the period of the year when values are higher than the selected threshold.

From this:

[image]

where the plane is shown but not as a section

To This:

[image]

Any suggestion?

Plying with alpha and camera elevation did not solve the issue

[image]

the plane still seems to be in front of the figure, not as a section

Comment: just reduce the alpha of the plane, so it hides the curve below it

Comment: I tried to play with alpha (0.1) and POV elevation but with no success, as the plan is still somehow in front of the graph

Comment: you should post the code so we can see how you are assigning the alpha values. Make some toy data so the code you post can be copied and run, don't rely on external data since we won't be able to run your code then

Comment: With Matplotlib, the plan is either in the front or in the back of the "cones". That's life. Matplotlib cannot do what you asked them to do. There are more 3D specialized Python modules, or external programs that can help you.

Comment: Any specific library or tool you can suggest me to try?

Comment: Sorry, I can't. I have no direct experience with that stuff. PS If you want me (or someone else) to be notified of your comment, use eg @gboffi to start your comment. I've seen your comment, clearly addressed to me, just by chance.

Comment: @gboffi  [Matplotlib's 3D Faq](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html) suggests [Mayavi](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/) for full 3D.

Answer (score 6):

## Drawing in 3 steps

As others pointed out, matplotlib's 3D capabilities are somewhat limited. To hide objects behind other objects, it uses the [painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm).  So, the objects are simply drawn back to front, and no objects are put partly before and partly behind some plane.  Matplotlib calculates some average depth of each object to define the order.  You can overwrite this order via `ax.computed_zorder = False`, as the automatic calculation is not always what is wished.

You could draw the "layers" yourself:

- the 3D surface
- then the plane
- then the part of the 3D surface that should be visible on top

An example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 51)
y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 51)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
np.random.seed(20220201)
Z = np.random.rand(*X.shape) ** 5
Z[X ** 2 + Y ** 2 > 30] = 0
Z = gaussian_filter(Z, sigma=2) * 100

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
ax.computed_zorder = False
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='turbo')
special_z = 16
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, np.full_like(Z, special_z), color='blue', alpha=0.4)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, np.where(Z >= special_z, Z, np.nan), cmap='turbo', vmin=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: partly hiding a 3D surface with matplotlib]

## Drawing layer by layer

An alternative way could be to draw the surface one layer at a time.
The example at the left shows the surface divided into 30 layers, the example at the right stops at a given height, visualizing the intersection.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 51)
y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 51)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
np.random.seed(20220201)
Z = np.random.rand(*X.shape) ** 5
Z[X ** 2 + Y ** 2 > 30] = 0
Z = gaussian_filter(Z, sigma=2) * 100

fig = plt.figure()
for which in ['left', 'right']:
    ax = fig.add_subplot(121 + (which == 'right'), projection="3d")
    ax.computed_zorder = False

    layers = np.linspace(Z.min(), Z.max(), 32)[1:-1]
    colors = plt.get_cmap('turbo', len(layers)).colors

    special_z = 16
    plane_drawn = False
    for layer, color in zip(layers, colors):
        if layer >= special_z and not plane_drawn:
            ax.plot_surface(X, Y, np.full_like(Z, special_z), color='blue', alpha=0.5, zorder=2)
            plane_drawn = True
        ax.contour(X, Y, Z, levels=[layer], offset=layer, colors=[color])
        if plane_drawn and which == 'right':
            break
plt.show()
```

[image: drawing a 3D surface layer by layer]