# How to get a plane to nicely intersect a 3D surface in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I am trying to edit my code to produce a nicer visual, this is the current output:
[image]

What I would like to change is the 3D graph on the left, is there a way to make that intersection of the surface and the plane look nicer? I don't need anything fancy here, just something that would make the intersection more clear looking. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.colors as colors

# Define the function to plot
def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2))

# Generate data for the x, y, and z coordinates
x = np.linspace(-6, 6, 100)
y = np.linspace(-6, 6, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['black'])

# Create a 3D figure and a contour plot side by side
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)

# Add labels and title to both subplots
ax1.set_xlabel('x')
ax1.set_ylabel('y')
ax1.set_zlabel('z')
ax1.set_title('3D Plot of f(x, y) = sin(sqrt(x^2 + y^2))')
ax2.set_xlabel('x')
ax2.set_ylabel('y')
ax2.set_title('Level Set Contour Plot of f(x, y) = sin(sqrt(x^2 + y^2))')

# Plot the surface on the left subplot
ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='jet')

i = 1 # intialize i
level_set_speed = .075 # how quickly the level sets expand
plane_speed = .05 # how quickly the plane moves up

for a in np.arange(-1,1,plane_speed): # controls the movement of the plane
    i += level_set_speed

    #Plot the plane moving up the surface on the left
    ax1.cla()
    plane = np.zeros_like(X)
    plane = np.zeros_like(X) + a
    ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='jet')
    ax1.plot_wireframe(X, Y, plane, color='black')

    # Plot the contour on the right subplot
    contour_levels = np.arange(Z.min(), Z.min()+i, i/2)
    ax2.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=contour_levels, cmap=cmap, extend='min')\
    
    #snapshot
    plt.pause(.1)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Any help, ideas or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It might be worth checking out Pyvista's plane clipping widget. https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/03-widgets/plane-widget.html

Comment: See also [3D surface plot with section plan in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75312202/3d-surface-plot-with-section-plan-in-matplotlib/75313704#75313704)

Comment: Note that 'jet' is a [bad choice for data visualization](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's your expected output. For me, I think you want to show the intersection plane fully. So I add some codes to remove the values smaller than the plane by adding a variable `Z_temp`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.colors as colors

# Define the function to plot
def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2))

# Generate data for the x, y, and z coordinates
x = np.linspace(-6, 6, 100)
y = np.linspace(-6, 6, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['black'])

# Create a 3D figure and a contour plot side by side
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)

# Add labels and title to both subplots
ax1.set_xlabel('x')
ax1.set_ylabel('y')
ax1.set_zlabel('z')
ax1.set_title('3D Plot of f(x, y) = sin(sqrt(x^2 + y^2))')
ax2.set_xlabel('x')
ax2.set_ylabel('y')
ax2.set_title('Level Set Contour Plot of f(x, y) = sin(sqrt(x^2 + y^2))')

# Plot the surface on the left subplot
ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='jet')


i = 1 # intialize i
level_set_speed = .075 # how quickly the level sets expand
plane_speed = .05 # how quickly the plane moves up

Z_temp = Z.copy()

for a in np.arange(-1,1.05,plane_speed): # controls the movement of the plane
    Z_temp = Z.copy()
    i += level_set_speed

    #Plot the plane moving up the surface on the left
    ax1.cla()
    plane = np.zeros_like(X)
    plane = np.zeros_like(X) + a
    
    Z_temp[Z<a] = np.nan
    
    ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z_temp, cmap='jet')
    ax1.plot_wireframe(X, Y, plane, color='black')
    ax1.set_zlim(np.nanmin(Z), np.nanmax(Z))

    # Plot the contour on the right subplot
    contour_levels = np.arange(np.nanmin(Z), np.nanmin(Z)+i, i/2)
    ax2.contourf(X, Y, Z, levels=contour_levels, cmap=cmap, extend='min')\
    
    #snapshot
    plt.pause(.1)

ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='jet')
    

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: Ah brilliant! The only issue here is that the bottom of the surface is now disappearing as the plane moves up, perhaps placing the ax1.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='jet') in a different spot would fix this?

Comment: Note that matplotlib plots in layers.  You can assign your own depth value (`zorder=...`, only one z-order per graphical element) and setting `ax.computed_zorder = False`.